# Ошибка при подключении нескольких форм к одной

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++

К `Form1` подключаю `Form2.h` и `Form3.h`. Как мне исправить следующие ошибки, если управлять этими двумя формами нужно именно отсюда?

Ошибки:

```
1>------ Построение начато: проект: Super_File_Manager, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Form2.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6143): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(251) : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6143): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IDataObject"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157): error C2371: IDataObject: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(251): см. объявление "IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6319): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6332): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6345): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6381): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6401): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6511): error C2872: IMessageFilter: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(263) : System::Windows::Forms::IMessageFilter IMessageFilter"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IMessageFilter"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6511): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IMessageFilter"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6557): error C2371: IMessageFilter: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(263): см. объявление "IMessageFilter"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13488): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13494): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13499): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13505): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13510): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13517): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(382): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(1165): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(1171): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3385): error C2872: IDropTarget: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(173) : System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget IDropTarget"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3385): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IDropTarget"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3425): error C2371: IDropTarget: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(173): см. объявление "IDropTarget"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3429): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3442): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(96): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(53) : System::IServiceProvider IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(96): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IServiceProvider"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103): error C2371: IServiceProvider: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(53): см. объявление "IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(120): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(241): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(251): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.h(6459): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.h(6461): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\users\debilian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\super_file_manager\super_file_manager\Form1.h(594): error C2871: Form2: пространство имен с таким именем не существует
1>c:\users\debilian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\super_file_manager\super_file_manager\Form1.h(616): error C2871: Form3: пространство имен с таким именем не существует
1>  Super_File_Manager.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6143): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(251) : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6143): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IDataObject"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157): error C2371: IDataObject: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(251): см. объявление "IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6319): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6332): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6345): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6381): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6401): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6511): error C2872: IMessageFilter: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(263) : System::Windows::Forms::IMessageFilter IMessageFilter"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IMessageFilter"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6511): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IMessageFilter"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6557): error C2371: IMessageFilter: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(263): см. объявление "IMessageFilter"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13488): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13494): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13499): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13505): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13510): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(13517): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(382): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(1165): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(1171): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3385): error C2872: IDropTarget: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(173) : System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget IDropTarget"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3385): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IDropTarget"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3425): error C2371: IDropTarget: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(173): см. объявление "IDropTarget"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3429): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oleidl.h(3442): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.h(6157) : IDataObject"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(96): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(53) : System::IServiceProvider IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(96): error C3699: *: это косвенное обращение невозможно использовать для типа "IServiceProvider"
1>          для продолжения работы компилятор заменил "*" на "^"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103): error C2371: IServiceProvider: переопределение; различные базовые типы
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(53): см. объявление "IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(120): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(241): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(251): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.h(6459): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.h(6461): error C2872: IServiceProvider: неоднозначный символ
1>          может быть "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider"
1>          или       "c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider"
1>c:\users\debilian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\super_file_manager\super_file_manager\Form1.h(594): error C2871: Form2: пространство имен с таким именем не существует
1>c:\users\debilian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\super_file_manager\super_file_manager\Form1.h(616): error C2871: Form3: пространство имен с таким именем не существует
1>  Создание кода...
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: Судя по сообщениям компилятора, у вас используется неуправляемый (нативный) на тип `IDataObject`, который является управляемым типом. И хорошо бы код увидеть.

Comment: @AlecanderPetrov, он ругается на подключение сразу двух заголовочных файлов форм. Код могу скинуть завтра, но он таков: `#pragma once`, затем включение `Form2.h` и `Form3.h`, а дальше, даже если оставить все у по умолчанию, все равно будут будут ошибки.

Comment: уберите `using namespace System::Windows::Forms` и обращайтесь к типам путем указания полного имени (прописывая пространство имен каждый раз)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не помогло, пишет то же самое + пишет, что формы не являются членами данного пространства имён.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в следующем распределении подключаемых файлов:

```
#pragma once
#include "Form2.h"
#include "Form3.h"
```